# How can I Fix WordPress Error - Critical Error on Site

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

This error shows up on my website. How can I fix it?

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare true_plugins_activate() (previously declared in /home/u106724943/domains/savvysage.store/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:7598) in /home/u106724943/domains/savvysage.store/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 7629

There has been a critical error on your website.

Comment: Try deactivating all the plugins and themes and activating plugin one by one to find the culprit plugin or theme.

Comment: It seems that `true_plugins_activate() function` is duplicate. Check if you are using plugins from the same author, that using the same `func name` in more than one of their plugins or maybe the funtion is redeclared in theme `functions.php`

Answer (score 0):

If you got like this `Fatal error`

Go to the url and check with the Original code of the plugin then you can understand the issue.
Check your php version

Finally check the error log then you can find where is the issue and how can you fixed it.